# How to access a View object in Eclipse from another class?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I've created a new view class which extends ViewPart for my Eclipse plugin.
That class holds a Browser object.
I wish to be able to set the URL from other classes, effectively something like myViewObject.browser.setURL(...)

But how can I access the view object? I don't have its reference when it is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `findView` method of `IWorkbenchPage` to find the view:

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = 
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow(),getActivePage();

IViewPart part = page.findView("my view id");

if (part instanceof MyViewClass) {
   MyViewClass myView = (MyViewClass)part;

   ... call methods on your view
}
```

where `MyViewClass` is your class extending `ViewPart`

Comment: If the view is closed there is no instance of your class anywhere, so you can't call any methods on it. Use IWorkbenchPage `showView` to show the view and create your class instance.